# CSS - Box background color change on drop menu when hovering on it - Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

Firstable i'm very noob in CSS/web coding so please forgive me...

I'm requesting your help because i'm still stuck on in my wordpress dev site customization.

I set up a border-radius, background color and hover style for my menu bar. The hover works well on the main navigation menu but when i scroll down the dropmenu with the border-radius configured, a "default" background appears with 4 grey corners. The background color should be the same as parent (#5b2121d4)

I didn't find an easy fix solution in Css code, and couldn't find the item target in google dev tools inspection.

Any idea about removing this "default" background ?

[Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYsWI.png)

This is my website dev platform : http://dev.achete-local.fr/boutique/

Thanks for your help

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0):

Remove the background colour from the sub menu.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. Which background ? I can't find it

Comment: Find the .sub-menu item in the inspect window. I can give you the CSS you need to add to remove it but your site appears to be down?